# Checking if folders exist from a user input in Python

Tags: python, file, directory, exists

I am trying to do a series of checks in a while True loop to see if a folder exists or a user error. In my folder I have two folders A and B. I will ask the user to Enter a folder name.

```
from os.path import exists

folder1_2 = input('Enter folder name: ')
i = (folder1, folder2)

while True:
    i = raw_input()
    does_it_exist = os.path.exists(i) # True/False
    if does_it_exist == False:
        print("The folder does not exist")            
        continue 
    if os.listdir(".") == False:
            print("folder not found")
        continue  
    if i('A', 'B') == False:
            print("not the same folder or user error")
        continue  
    break 
print("All tests passed successfully!")

return [folder1_2]
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question. What is wrong with this code other than indentation?

Comment: `os.listdir(".") == False` that is hardly useful... `os.listdir` returns a list, so that's never `False`

Comment: also `if i('A', 'B') == False:` is wrong. `i` is a string, not a function. please read more about python.

Comment: [os.path.isdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir)

Comment: Your code is in different spacetime probably.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    f1 = input("Folder1?") #asking user for input
    f2 = input("Folder2?")
    if not os.path.exists(f1) or not os.path.exists(f2):
        print("some error message")
        continue
    if not os.path.isdir(f1) or not os.path.isdir(f2):
        print("another error message")
        continue
    if (f1 == f2): #are these folders the same
        print("one more error message")
        continue
    break
print("all tests passed successfully!")
```

I hope this helps.